# What makes an API 'rich'?

Tags: terminology, definition

So I was having a conversation, and it occurred to me -- what is a 'rich' API?  What is a 'poor' API?  It's a term often thrown around, and almost feels like it might be marketing speech, and I'd like to know if it actually has some sort of programatic meaning, like 'RESTful API'.

Comment: This is probably better asked on http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I can see your argument, if 'rich' isn't something that can be answered concretely.  I was comparing it to RESTful API, which is something that can be defined in the context of *this* site.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen no, it is poor fit over there for the same reasons as it is poor fit here.  Recommended reading: **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, this question is probably too broad for StackOverflow, and the answer is quite subjective.

I don't think there is a strict definition of "rich" API, and it indeed may be marketing speech. The antonym of "rich" API is not "poor", but "minimalistic".

E.g., imagine you are building an API for logical computations. In theory an API that contains just one function NAND(a,b) would be enough to perform any possible logical computation. You can express all other logical operations in terms of NAND, e.g. `AND(a,b) = NAND(NAND(a,b), NAND(a,b))`, but it would be quite cumbersome and probably inefficient. So, the one-function NAND API would be sufficient, but definitely not rich. A rich API, in addition to NAND, would also define things like OR(a,b), AND(a,b), and XOR(a,b), and perhaps some others.